# How to find out which CSS element forces a specific size?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

I am writing a home dashboard (using [Quasar](https://quasar.dev/)) and stumbled upon a problem I would like to debug. The intent of this question is to **understand how I should approach the debugging**, but if someone has also the answer to my problem it is of course very much welcome :)

In **Chrome**, one of the elements has strange behaviour. It is a 2x2 CSS Grid of `<emploi-du-temps>` components

```
<template>
(...)
    <div class="emploi-du-temps" v-if='displayEdt' ref="edt">
      <emploi-du-temps class="" :data='dataEdt' when="today" who="michael"></emploi-du-temps>
      <emploi-du-temps class="" :data='dataEdt' when="tomorrow" who="michael"></emploi-du-temps>
      <emploi-du-temps class="" :data='dataEdt' when="today" who="martin"></emploi-du-temps>
      <emploi-du-temps class="" :data='dataEdt' when="today" who="martin"></emploi-du-temps>
    </div>
(...)
<template>

<style scoped>
.emploi-du-temps {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 70fr 30fr;
}
</style>
```

and as you can see below, the total height of the `div` does not sum up to the heights of the rows (there is no padding/margin added, all four components behave the same):

[image]

[image]

In other words, there is this space between the last row (you see "martin" there) and the light blue element I want to investigate. The bottom rectangle chart in DevTools `Element → Styles` does not show any margins/padding so it must come from somewhere else.

Now, the strange part is that the same page displayed in **Firefox** behaves as expected (no extra space):

[image]

My question is **not** "what is wrong" (there is not code provided, I would probably need to dump the whole app as simple JSFiddel tests behave normally. But hey, if someone knows I am all ears) but rather **"how can I use DevTools to investigate where that space comes from"**.

Comment: The bad news is you possibly can't. That has all the hallmarks of a Chromium bug caused by the order in which the layout is computed. The evidence of how that layout was reached might be gone, and not visible in Dev Tools at all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Computed tab in Chrome Dev Tools? If something is setting computed CSS property, it will be visible and on hover, you will see a small arrow which will lead you to the CSS rule with that setting:

[image]

If it's "greyed out" then you should look into browser defaults. In the past, people used CSS reset snippets but you should apply resets more consciously.

Also this can help:

```js
// create a bookmark and use this code as the URL, you can now toggle the css on/off
// thanks+credit: https://dev.to/gajus/my-favorite-css-hack-32g3
javascript: (function() {
    var domStyle = document.createElement("style");
    domStyle.append(
            '* { color:#0f0!important;outline:solid #f00 1px!important; background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.2) !important; }\
            * * { background-color: rgba(0,255,0,.2) !important; }\
            * * * { background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.2) !important; }\
            * * * * { background-color: rgba(255,0,255,.2) !important; }\
            * * * * * { background-color: rgba(0,255,255,.2) !important; }\
            * * * * * * { background-color: rgba(255,255,0,.2) !important; }\
            * * * * * * * { background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.2) !important; }\
            * * * * * * * * { background-color: rgba(0,255,0,.2) !important; }\
            * * * * * * * * * { background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.2) !important; }'
    );
    document.body.appendChild(domStyle);
})();
```

If you enter it into the browser console it will show a grid of your page. Sometimes it helps me to investigate such problems.